# C++ QuickSort not sorting

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, quicksort

```
void quickSort(vector<double> unsortedData, int leftBound, int rightBound) {

    if (leftBound < rightBound) {
        double i = partitionStep(unsortedData, leftBound, rightBound);
        quickSort(unsortedData, leftBound, i-1);
        quickSort(unsortedData, i + 1, rightBound);
    }
}

double partitionStep(vector<double> unsortedData, int leftBound, int rightBound) {

    double pivot = unsortedData[rightBound];

    while (leftBound <= rightBound) {

        while ((unsortedData[leftBound] < pivot)) {
            leftBound++;
        }
        while ((unsortedData[rightBound] > pivot)) {
            rightBound--;
        }

        if (unsortedData[leftBound] == unsortedData[rightBound]) {
            leftBound++;
        } else if (leftBound < rightBound) {
            double temp = unsortedData[leftBound];
            unsortedData[leftBound] = unsortedData[rightBound];
            unsortedData[rightBound] = temp;
        }
    }

    return rightBound;
}
```

I need to sort a vector of doubles. This code runs but the vector is not sorted at the end. It's probably something that I am overlooking. Thoughts?

Comment: Why you're returning double from partitionStep? Shouldn't it return int?

Comment: you need to have the function take a reference rather than a value for input

Comment: The easiest way to sort a vector of doubles is to use the sort routine from the standard library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A high level description of your `quickSort` routine is:

- Take as input a copy of the original vector and the endpoints of a range
- Do stuff with the copy
- Discard the copy

which isn't particularly useful. Change the input argument to `vector<double>&` so that you're doing stuff with a *reference* to the original vector rather than a copy.

Comment: Should it not be `vector<double> &`?